# Maximum recursion depth error while implementing DFS algorithm in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory, depth-first-search

I was watching this [MIT ocw video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfSk24UTFS8) about implementation of DFS algorithm . I understood it perfectly and tried to implement it on the adjacency list of a graph.

The following is my code:

```
parent={}
def DFSv(adj,s):
  for v in adj[s]:
    if v not in parent:
        parent[v]=s
    DFSv(adj,v)
def DFS(adj):
  for s in adj:
        if s not in parent:
            parent[s]="None"
        DFSv(adj,s)

a={1: [2, 5], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 4, 6], 4: [3, 5, 6], 5: [1, 2, 4], 6: [3, 4]}
DFS(a,1,6)
```

Even after increasing the recursion limit using sys module, the error doesn't go.

Specifications of graph:

```
vertices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
edges    = [(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4), (4, 5), (6, 4)]
```

Comment: Is your graph a tree?

Comment: @NiVeR No, its an unweighted graph .

Comment: Hmm not what I asked, does it contain cycles?

Comment: @NiVeR No you should check out the edited question

Comment: What is the termination condition for your routine?

Comment: @n.m. There was no termination condition mentioned in the video. I think the if-else should be enough for termination.

Comment: @aditya where are you calling the DFS module?

Comment: If you think the program should not terminate, you have nothing to complain about. If you think it should terminate, well, you claim you understood the video perfectly, so you should have no.problem explaining when it should terminate.

Comment: @n.m. I think the program will terminate when backtracking leads back to the starting vertex. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @VarunNarisetty MY code had some massive blunders,please check the newly edited version.

Comment: "I think the program will terminate when backtracking leads back to the starting vertex." Show this place in the code.